# (Django) how to get month name?

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a query like below:

```
today = datetime.datetime.now()
month = today.month
print month
```

and it outputs:

```
3
```

I want to display the month name like "March". What should I do?

Comment: None of the following answers are good for me because they don't take request's locale into consideration...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

use the datetime string formatting method, e.g.

```
>>> today.strftime('%B')
'March'
```

for more info, and a full list of formatting codes, see [the python `datetime` docs](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Comment: People using timezone can do the same using: `timezone.now().strftime('%B')`

Answer (score 34):

For English only, you can use the datetime string formatting method of Python, e.g.

```
>>> today.strftime('%B')
'March'
```

You can also use Django methods, which will return the name **in the current activated language**.

In a Django template you can also use:

```
{{ a_date|date:'F' }}
```

In a Django view function:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import date
date(a_date, 'F')
```

You can test the later in the Django shell (`python manage.py shell`) for e.g. Spanish with:

```
In [1]: from django.utils.translation import get_language, activate

In [2]: activate('es')

In [3]: get_language()
Out[3]: 'es'

In [4]: import datetime

In [5]: today = datetime.date.today()

In [6]: from django.template.defaultfilters import date

In [7]: date(today, 'F')
Out[7]: u'Septiembre'
```

Comment: To people that looks for all [date format characters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date)

Answer (score 10):

The [Calendar API](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name) is another option.

```
calendar.month_name[3] # would return 'March'
```

Comment: How would you localize this string?

Answer (score 3):

I solved the same by registering a custom template tag to help me apply it on any template page that requires the month name.

templatetags/etras.py

```
from django import template
import calendar

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def month_name(value):
    return calendar.month_name[value]
```

Usage in template:

```
{% load extras %}
{{ month_figure|month_name }}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
datetime.datetime.strftime(today, '%B') # Outputs 'March'
```

or

```
datetime.datetime.strftime(today, '%b') # Outputs 'Mar'
```

http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 2):

`Month Name` to `Month Number` and vice versa in `python`

By Using calendar [calendar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html)

Creating a `reverse dictionary` would be a reasonable way to do this:

`dict((val,k) for k,v in enumerate(calendar.month_abbr))`

Answer (score 1):

Python's calendar module will do that for you, see [calendar.month_name](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html)

```
month = calendar.month_name[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use strftime:

```
>>> today = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> today.strftime("%B")
'March'
>>>
```