# How to get localized month name?

Tags: django

Related question: [(Django) how to get month name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621388/django-how-to-get-month-name)

I have the month number, and want to the corresponding month name. How to do it taking into consideration the request locale? All the answers given to the related question uses the process locale, not the request locale.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set the locale [per request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-url-patterns)  (do not forget the middleware), and just use the standard i18n method `from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _`

Comment: This does not answer the question

Answer (score 1):

The [`django.utils.dates`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.2.5/django/utils/dates.py#L24) module has the dictionary that you are looking for:

```py
from django.utils import dates

def get_month_name(month: int) -> str:
    """Localized (lazy) name of the month."""
    try:
        return dates.MONTHS[month]
    except KeyError as e:
        raise ValueError(f'expected 1 <= month <= 12, got {month}') from e
```

Usage example:

```
>>> from django.utils.translation import activate
>>> activate('nl')
>>> get_month_name(6)
'juni'
>>> activate('tr')
>>> get_month_name(6)
'Haziran'
```

If you want the abbreviated name, `django.utils.dates.MONTHS_AP` for Associated Press style, or `django.utils.dates.MONTHS_3` for 3-letter  abbrevations, can be used instead.