# Getting month name on Django template from timezone.localtime()

Tags: django, date

Im trying to display the month name of the datetime object on a django template. This is how Im sending the date:

```
{
..

'today': timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
..
}
```

On the template Im doing this, I have tried what this question has: [(Django) how to get month name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621388/django-how-to-get-month-name)

But still I'm not getting the desired result, maybe there's a difference with timezone.locatime() vs datetime.now()?:

```
{{ today|date:"F" }}
```

However Im only getting and empty blank space where whe month name should be. Can anyone help me correct my error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(Django) how to get month name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621388/django-how-to-get-month-name)

Comment: What are the values of `USE_TZ` and `TIME_ZONE` settings?

Comment: `USE_TZ = True` and `TIME_ZONE = 'America/Guatemala'`

Comment: Are you sure your template context is being populated correctly? What happens if you just try `{{ today }}`?