# Django In views not able to get month name from month date

Tags: python, django

I have one field Monthly it is stored whole date(2022-01-19)

When I tried in my views

```
{{calendar.month_name[metric.monthly.month]}}
```

It gives one error

```
Could not parse the remainder: '[metric.monthly.month]' from 'calendar.month_name[metric.monthly.month]'
```

but it give 1 when I am doing

```
metric.monthly.month
```

anyhelp

Comment: Is it possible to use get items as python dictionary, I am guessing not. Instead I believe you should use `{{calendar.month_name.metric.monthly.month }}`. But better option can be using template tags with `{{ date_field|date:"F" }}`.

Comment: This is a duplicate question of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621388/django-how-to-get-month-name/9621418
Try to give a look at that question, the answer is right there.

Comment: You can not subscript in the Django template language.